# ¿Existe algo parecido a un precompilador JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, compilador, modular

Bueno antes de escuchar sugerencias de automatizadores como gulp o grunt, explicaré en detalle lo que deseo; imaginé este panorama:

### desarrollo/secciones/objeto.js

```js
{
  // atributos...
}
```

### desarrollo/funcion.js

```js
function haceHalgo(){
  var objeto = @include('secciones/objeto.js');
  // mas código...
}
```

### produccion/funcion.js *«resultado tras compilar»*

```js
(
   function haceHalgo(){
     var objeto = {
        // atributos...
     };
     // mas código...
   }
})();
```

Podrán notar que las concatenaciones usando tuberías no son útiles aquí puesto que el código de un archivo va incrustado entre otro archivo y no antes o después, busco algo muy parecido a lo que se hace con los Trait en PHP que al final genere un fichero para producción a partir de pequeñas secciones modulares en desarrollo.

Si por al acaso sugieren RequireJs debo decir que lo he usado y me encanta poder modularizar de esa manera puedo crear objetos requerirlos y consumirlos pero no resuelve en detalle esta pregunta pues todo ello pasa en producción y yo deseo es un precompilador para generar archivos en tiempo de desarrollo, ademas entre otras cosas no siempre me es útil, por lo menos no para todos los proyectos en donde use angular, si bien he usado AngularAMD.js ademas de una librería que me diseñe para trabajar angular como AMD, debo decir que aunque posible preferiría no hacerlo para algunos proyectos en especial.

Otra nota es que por favor no sugieran soluciones como concatenar secciones como generalmente es posible ver en plantillas de librerías javascript:

```js
(
   function haceHalgo(){
     var objeto =
```

```js
{
   // atributos...
};
```

```js
   // mas código...
   }
})();
```

Desde ya muchas gracias, se que quizás es un poco alocado lo que estoy buscando pero me sería muy informativo.

Comment: Te recomiendo buscar sobre `Generic PreProcessor` (`gpp`), una aplicación autónoma; o sobre [`preprocess`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/preprocess), un módulo para node.js. Este último se puede usar desde `gulp`. Ambos permiten *incluir* archivos externos, definir *macros*, ...

Comment: En una búsqueda rápida encontré: https://github.com/grassator/karma-generic-preprocessor y otros enlaces sobre karma que me orientan mas por los autocompletadores y herramientas , podrías orientarme con un ejemplo simple de uso a ver si me da una luz en el tema.

Comment: Los que te indico son similares al *preprocesador* de C/C++. Colocas `include "archivo"` en el código, llamas al pre-procesador, y coloca el archivo indicado **dentro** de tu código. Entre otras varias cosas, como, por ejemplo, incluir/excluir determinadas líneas de tu código. En sus *homepages* hay info y ejemplos.

Comment: Encontré esto y aunque parece prometedor http://files.nothingisreal.com/software/gpp/gpp.html no menciona JS por ningún lado, así que decidí buscar en npm y allí encontré esto:  https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-gpp sinceramente me indica como instalarlo y ejecutarlo pero no me plantea un ejemplo claro «es a esto a lo que te refieres»